# android set listview position not work

Tags: android, android-listview

i have a stackFromBottom `ListView` , how can i set the position of listView after setting adapter

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
         public void run() {
           list.setAdapter(adapter);
           list.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
             list.requestFocusFromTouch();
             list.setSelection(10);
             list.requestFocus();
            }
           });
          }
         });
```

Comment: Wat do you want should happen on doing list.setSelected(10)??

Comment: show Tenth item in list

Comment: Sry did'nt get you. Please explain the scenario of your case. I mean as to show where????

Comment: i just want set the position of list ,Suppose we have a list of 20 item, how can i show Third item in list ? (show in view)

Answer (score 1):

ok i found the answer :

```
       list.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
          list.setSelectionFromTop(3,20);
          }
         }, 500);
```

Comment: yes. you should not use set selection immediately after set adapter, its common practice.